# vb.net passing a value of text box in javascript function

Tags: javascript, vb.net

MotherTongueTxtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur","val_Length(MotherTongueTxtBox.text,"hi friends",Length);")

in the above statement val_length s a javascript function in tat function the first parameter shd b the contents of the text box ,the second parameter s a string type, 
is the statement correct i think it s wrong can u suggest a correct valid statement please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a little trouble understanding your question, but I think you're asking that the first parameter be the textbox text, and the second be the length of the textbox text. This I think should work:

```
MotherTongueTxtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur","val_Length(this.value,this.value.length)");
```

Remember that the above will render the html like:

```
<input type="text" onblur="val_Length(this.value, this.value.length)" />
```

In your original statement, the resulting (*incorrect*) html would have been something like:

```
<input type="text" onblur="val_Length(,0)"/>
```

Since `MotherTongueTxtBox.Text` and `.Length` would have been `string.empty` and `0` respectively (unless it already had initial values...)

**EDIT:**

Thanks for marking as solution. Just as a side note, one thing you may want to consider, is you don't need to pass `this.value.length` in as a parameter, since you're already passing in `this.value`. You could determine the length within your function. Just an idea though like this:

```
MotherTongueTxtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur","val_Length(this.value, 'Hi')");
```

And then in your javascript function:

```
function val_Length(value, myString) {

    var length = value.length;

    ....

}
```

Comment: friend i need to pass a string value too , along with other parameters

Comment: MotherTongueTxtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur","val_Length(this.value,"hi",this.value.length)");                    

here am passing a string"hi" along with it now is the syntax correct